# HTML dropdown's custom attribute empty in chrome, works fine in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This is my code.

```
var arrSelectElements   = document.getElementsByTagName( "SELECT" );

for (var i = 0; i < arrSelectElements.length; i++) { 
      alert(arrSelectElements[i].DataSource); //code to use datasource value
}
```

It simply gets a list of all select elements in aspx file, and finds out the datasource name. Here is the code that binds the dropdown in C# file.

```
ddlSubsidiary.Attributes.Add("DataSource", "Subsidiary");
ddlSubsidiary.Attributes.Add("DataMember", "DISubsidiary");
```

Now, this code in IE works perfect. alert returns the name properly. But in Chrome, it always returns `undefined`.

Is it by design or am I missing something here?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the HTML in your question too.  Even better, you could setup the example at https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: It is a simple select in the html file, nothing else. Can't create a fiddle, as the C# code is server side, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the attribute value with the DOM element property in Internet Explorer, you have to use IE8 or older, or to run in compatibility mode (equivalent to IE7). In these old versions, the custom attributes can be retrieved in client code using the expando property with the same name:

```
var dataSource = ctl.DataSource;
var dataMember = ctl.DataMember;
```

From what I have read, this technique worked only in Internet Explorer, not in other browsers ([HTML Custom Attributes Not Working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894866/html-custom-attributes-not-working-in-chrome)).

[Since version 9](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/ie9-internet-explorer-9-changes-developers-should-know-about/), it doesn't work in Internet Explorer either. The `getAttribute` method must be used to get the attribute value in client code:

```
var dataSource = ctl.getAttribute('DataSource');
var dataMember = ctl.getAttribute('DataMember');
```

Comment: Not in office, so can't test the full code. But, let me create a simple project to test. I think this is the problem. let me test, and get back to you.

Comment: It works. Thanks for the help. I didn't even know that using `.PropertyName` doesn't work all the time.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say why IE6+ browser returns undefined, but my guess is that the checking event gets executed before the assignment event actually occurred.  Quirk mode only uses 1 thread for everything while newer browser uses separate thread for DOM manipulation and render.